# Why was this reasonable question deleted by Community inside of 2 minutes?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, community

Ok, [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341595/c-sharp-get-item-from-list) wasn't a great question but apparently it made it through all the input filters.

What surprises me is that it was deleted by Community in less than 2 minutes, no chance for anybody to vote or comment.

What's up?

Comment: Maybe because he used the F* word.

Comment: Even if the OP did say "fu​cked", does it really warrant a red-flag deletion instead of an edit?

Comment: @Mysticial not really. But sometimes the community takes its own turn.

Answer (score 12):

A developer (not naming names) insta-flag-deleted it with an "offensive" flag. Not exactly sure why he chose that path, but it has been restored now.

Comment: Think it's worth trying to contact that dev somehow then and ask, so it won't happen again. It's just by chance this question was saved.